# Nginx redirect from 80 to 8080

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am using nginx as a load balancer, but there is a question that confused me.
My nginx.conf:

```
upstream backend {
    ip_hash;
    server 172.16.117.200:8080 weight=1;
    server 172.16.117.201:8080 weight=4;
}
server {
    location / {
        listen       80;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /var/www;
    location /aa {
        if ($request_uri ~* ^.*/.*$) {
            rewrite ^/(mp)/(.*)$  /$1/index.php?q=$2 last;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I type `172.16.1.200/aa/` in the browser, everything is ok, but if I type `172.16.117.200/aa` (without slash) in the browser, the address will be redirect to `http://172.16.117.200:8080/aa/`

What's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

if file not 0644  not correct or file not found will redirect with    real port  make sure it's found and god 0644   and some times it's    not autoindex or you not set index at nginx.conf  make redirect to    index.php   try use 172.16.1.200/aa/index.php

into blancer

```
upstream backend {
    ip_hash;
    server 172.16.117.200:8080 weight=1;
    server 172.16.117.201:8080 weight=4;
}
server {
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        listen       80;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

into  172.16.117.200 nginx.conf

```
server {
    server_name  172.16.117.200;
            rewrite ^/(mp)/(.*)$  /$1/index.php?q=$2 last;

    location / {
        listen       *:8080;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
root  /aa;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit this? Are you talking about 0644 file permissions?